# Alter Type: add attribute if it doesn't already exist

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

Is there a way to alter an object type to add an attribute only if it doesn't already exist? I am writing a script that will be run on multiple databases. I'm trying to avoid unnecessary PLS-00410 errors (duplicate fields in RECORD,TABLE or argument list are not permitted).

Something like the following:

```
ALTER TYPE employee
ADD ATTRIBUTE --IF NOT EXISTS
  (address2 VARCHAR2(30))
CASCADE;
```

If there is no elegant inline solution like the above, is there a system table I can look at? ALL_TYPES only lists the number of attributes per type, not the specific attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ALL_TYPE_ATTRS` appears to be what you're looking for.  It's a child of `ALL_TYPES` for OBJECT types.